# jquery dialog icon positioning

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using jquery dialog as in
 http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-windows-like-interface-with-jquery-ui/ and i have placed a maximize icon, but the problem is that i am not able to position it from right like

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar-rest{ position: absolute; right: 23px; top: 50%; width: 19px; margin: -10px 0 0 0; padding: 1px; height: 18px; }
```

It's getting positioned default on the left corner, whereas if i mention the `left:1025px;` that's working fine , what's obstructing it the right property.

I am using the jquery smoothness theme `"jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css"`

Can anybody help me out with this?

Comment: try adding `float:right` to your css

Comment: tried.doesnt seem to work.It's still the same.

Comment: have you tried removing `margin` property

Comment: This may be useful for you http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: yes.It's still the same.

Comment: Can you prepare a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: actually the left property works fine, but i need to position the icon from right so that on stretching the dialog ,icon remains there itself and right property is not applying atall.

Comment: i am too new for this, and i am having trouble creating the fiddle.I tried but i think i might have missed some basics in those,like where do i add the reference scripts and the css reference??

Comment: is there a class called ".ui-dialog-titlebar-rest" in jquery ui css file?

Comment: yes i have added that class in the jquery ui css and defined positions there

Comment: its not a good practice to change/edit in the jquery ui css file, instead of that try to override the css in some other css file, because when you put the next version of jquery ui you will lose those styles which you have entered

Answer (score 1):

There has to be another style called `.ui-dialog-titlebar-close` for close button, the styles of that must have been applied, so try inserting your maximized icon before that like the following,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#trigger').click(function(){
      $("#dialog").dialog();
      $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").before('<img id="maximize" name="maximize" src="images/imageName.jpg"/>');
   }); 
});
```

Styles

```
<style type="text/css">
   #maximize{
     float:right;/* insert whatever the styles you want here.*/
   }
</style>
```

Html

```
<input name="trigger" id="trigger" type="text" />
<div id="dialog" style="display:none">
    <div>
        Your Dialog content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i am not sure what's that trigger click function, i tried with adding that before function like     $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").before('<img id="dialog_id" name="maximize"  src="css/flick/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png" />); but it doesnt seem to appear

Comment: Actually the problem was it was clashing with a different class name, on renaming that class name , it working perfectly fine. Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: nice to help you out @jeev1989